# AWS ECR : uploading docker image give below error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

When I tried to upload docker image

```
$ $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-southeast-2)
Error response from daemon: Get https://XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/v2/: EOF
```

I can able to docker run successfully on locally

also image tagged properly

```
1. windows 10  
2. aws cli 1.17.4   
3. docker 19.03.5
```

** ** note:

```
this is working now after upgrade the commands using aws cli 2.0
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ...ecr_image_url 
***
```

**

Comment: Do you enabled access to s3. I think calling ecr also requires being able to use s3.

Comment: I can access s3 using my machine console I tried aws s3 ls it is giving list of buckets...is it you mean to say?

Comment: do you need sudo ?

Comment: What platform is your local and what is the one where you are getting this?

Comment: Also, did you try it in 2 steps - without $() in the first command - does it give you proper docker login token?

Comment: @taleodor yes it  giving the error only without anything else

Comment: I am using windows 10 aws cli 1.7.4 and docker 19.03.5

Comment: Your error looks like a line ending issue inside aws cli - Windows being platform confirms this suspicion. And since your aws cli is pretty old, I think you should try upgrading it first of all. Offtopic side note: aws ecr is probably the worst registry out there due to this weird login they have.

Comment: my aws cli is 1.17.4 should I try to use aws cli 2 ??

Comment: aws-cli/1.17.4 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.15.11

Comment: 1.17.4 should be fine, I was thinking about 1.7.4 at first. So you should try uninstalling / reinstalling from package - things like that. Also multiple workarounds possible - i.e., WSL, dockerized version.